# convert string to audio input in java

Tags: java, string, audio, javasound

I want to play a sound in java.

I have my string with location of sound static `String s1 = "../files/song.wav";`
I have my file which gets passed path to string `File yourFile = new File(s1);`

And I have my method:

```
public void playCorrectSound(String song) throws IOException, LineUnavailableException  {
    try {
        AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Clip.class.getResourceAsStream(correctSong));
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audio);
        clip.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

This line gives error `AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(song);` as it needs (song) to be converted to a compatible type but how do i do it?

Exception is "no suitable method found for getAudioInputStream(String)"

Comment: what's the exception?

Comment: The parameter is `song`, yet you try to get the resource with `correctSong`, is this OK or just a typo?

Comment: no suitable method found for getAudioInputStream(String)

Answer (score 0):

[**i think you are after this one.**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioFileFormat%28java.io.File%29)

```
AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(File file)
```

The other function you should use:

```
AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(targetEncoding, sourceStream)
```

Where you need to pass the encoding. or:

```
AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(targetFormat, sourceStream)
```

Which requires AudioFormat to be passed.

[Check the JAVADOc.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream%28javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat.Encoding,%20javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream%29)